# How to binding User Control in MVVM Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a **User Control**(next UC) with **label**. I need on **button** click change a UC label content. On UC  codebehind i create **DependencyProperty** and methods to change a **label**.

```
public string InfoLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this.GetValue(InfoLabelProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(InfoLabelProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void InfoLabelChangeCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 uc = d as UserControl1;

        uc.CInfoLabel.Content = uc.InfoLabel;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InfoLabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InfoLabel", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(InfoLabelChangeCallback)));
```

On ShellView i got Binding on control and button.

```
<c:UserControl1 InfoLabel="{Binding InfoLabel1}" />
<Button  x:Name="ChangeUserControllButton"/>
```

On ShellViewModel I have Binding **InfoLabel1**.

```
private string infoLabel= "something";

    public string InfoLabel1
    {
        get
        {
            return infoLabel;
        }
        set
        {
            infoLabel = value;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeUserControllButton()
    {
        InfoLabel1 = "Hello world";
    }
```

The problem is When a **UC** is initialize, then it`s work. I mean **label** from UC will have content **"something"**, but when I Click on button, content not changing to "Hello world". How to make it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View model needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so as to be able to notify UI that it should refresh/update because the bound model has changed. I believe that there is already a base class that provides that functionality.

Reference [Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro/PropertyChangedBase.cs)

Update `ShellViewModel` to be derived from `PropertyChangedBase` and then in property call one of the available methods that would allow your view model to notify UI of property changed.

```
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase {

    private string infoLabel= "something";
    public string InfoLabel1 {
        get {
            return infoLabel;
        }
        set {
            infoLabel = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
            //Or
            //Set(ref infoLabel, value);
        }
    }

    public void ChangeUserControllButton() {
        InfoLabel1 = "Hello world";
    }

}
```

Read more at https://caliburnmicro.com/ to get examples of how to use the framework.